How do I determine the climate of a tidally-locked water-world planet around a red dwarf?
I am wondering what I can expect the weather, temperatures, etc. for a tidally locked planet around a red dwarf. How I can determine biomes and general climate based on location around the planet when considering wind currents, sunlight conditions, etc.? Would there be constant, worldwide storms? Or would the seas have already been evaporated away? Just some things I'm unsure of. 
My habitable world is orbiting a 0.584 M☉, K6.7V red dwarf star. It has a very Earth-like atmosphere with;

Atmospheric pressure at 1.34 atm.
Oxygen at 16.333% (compared to Earth's 20.95%), Carbon Dioxide at 0.09% (compared to Earth's 0.04%), Argon at 0.67% (compared to Earth's 0.93%),  And lastly Nitrogen at ~82.907% (compared to Earth's 78.08%)
Greenhouse effect equivalent to Earth (will change, I'm really not sure. My rough calculations say it'd be like, 5x stronger than Earth with the CO2 level...)

My planet has a semi-major axis of 0.34 AU, 0.788 M⊕, and has an average temperature of 14C.
I'm hoping to have it habitable globally, with plenty of air and water currents. 
My continents will be below the surface of the water, enabling me to have complex wind current systems while still having a water-world at the surface. I'm unsure how deep just yet.
 Also!! How bad will flares be for my planet if it had a semi-major axis of 0.34 AU? I'll probably make a new question for this addition if it's too unrelated.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

As currently written, this is asking too many questions - the last part about flares absolutely needs to be its own question.  Being tidally locked to the primary, the sunny side will bake and the dark side will freeze, but an answer of how much that will happen for all locations on the planet and all the weather systems associated would require a book. You are also specifying that all continents are under water, then asking whether the oceans will have boiled away.  Suggest that you narrow down to asking about one area (eg equatorial terminator region) for any chance of an answer. (Cont'd)

Note that the automatic Community Bot is able to detect algorithmically that this question is a problem before humans even look at it, which is always a bad sign.
